# Выбор числа существительного

Tags: число, существительные

Как правильно: *три самки енота* или *три самки енотов*?

Comment: Слово "енота" в данном случае означает вид млекопитающих, к которому принадлежат эти три самки. Если же сказать "три самки енотов", то получилось бы, что речь идёт о трёх конкретных енотах, чьими "подругами" являются эти три самки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный вариант *три самки енота*.

Comment: Здесь не действует никакое правило, здесь руководствуются логикой.  Три самки енотов ( енотов больше, чем один). Получается, что у определенного количества енотов три самки. Поэтому правильно: три самки енота.